# Can't find touchpad settings

Tags: windows-8, drivers, touchpad, tablet

I bought recently a Lenovo Miix 2 (11in, i5, 4Go version). Good skin and perfs, but I have a problem accessing the touchpad settings.

I don't know if there's multitouch, but first, I can't scroll, and the right click fires itself even when I click on the left of the touchpad. I just want to find a list of settings to fix this (like potentially disable rigth click when using trackpad and only fire it by touching the screen...).

I search on Windows 8 settings, empty, and it's not a Synaptics/Elan driver. Is there any way te change this, by using a generic driver, developing a tool, modifying system files, or anything else?

Comment: Before we can help, you need to identify the device for us, since we don't have access to that information.

Comment: I don't know it, the device's properties say that it's a Microsoft product, he's detected as mouse HID, but I can't find the exact reference...